# Executor/Launchy alternative for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, launchy, keystrokes

I am a new Ubuntu user and am looking for an alternative to [Executor](http://executor.dk/) or Launchy, both keystroke launchers. I have tried Gnome DO which is very similar to Launchy and it's good but I still miss Executor's functionality.

The major difference between Launchy and Executor is the the emphasis on user-defined keywords, which allow users to set keywords for launching any given application. In other words you can create your own commands/keystrokes.

I also don't like Gnome DO indexing all of my programs, as I don't use all of them. Instead I prefer assigning my keywords/progs/folders paths manually.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've managed to be pretty happy with Gnome-Do, but obviously you clearly state it doesn't seem right for you.. Maybe you can tune its settings to your needs? +1 Good question, regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Launchy is [available for Linux](http://www.launchy.net/download.php#linux) -- having only used it on Windows (I use GNOME 3 on Linux, and an app launcher seems superfluous there), does the Windows version have any feature not available on its Linux counterpart yet?

Answer (score 1):

I personally user [Kupfer](http://kaizer.se/wiki/kupfer/). It looks a bit like GnomeDO but is faster and more stable.
You can install an up-to-date version trough ubuntu-tweak. I forgot, you can assign programs and folders as favourites